# Join lists by value

Tags: python, performance, list, for-loop, dictionary

Is there an efficient way to merge two lists of tuples in python, based on a common value. Currently, I'm doing the following:

```
name = [
         (9, "John", "Smith"),
         (11, "Bob", "Dobbs"),
         (14, "Joe", "Bloggs")
         ]

occupation = [
              (9, "Builder"),
              (11, "Baker"),
              (14, "Candlestick Maker")
              ]

name_and_job = []

for n in name:
    for o in occupation:
        if n[0] == o[0]:
            name_and_job.append( (n[0], n[1], n[2], o[1]) )


print(name_and_job)
```

returns:

```
[(9, 'John', 'Smith', 'Builder'), (11, 'Bob', 'Dobbs', 'Baker'), (14, 'Joe', 'Bloggs', 'Candlestick Maker')]
```

While this code works perfectly fine for small lists, it's *incredibly* slow for longer lists with millions of records. Is there a more efficient way to write this?

**EDIT** The numbers in the first column are unique.

**EDIT** Modified @John Kugelman's code slightly. Added a get(), just in case the names dictionary doesn't have a matching key in the occupation dictionary:

```
>>>> names_and_jobs = {id: names[id] + (jobs.get(id),) for id in names}
>>>> print(names_and_jobs)
{9: ('John', 'Smith', None), 11: ('Bob', 'Dobbs', 'Baker'), 14: ('Joe', 'Bloggs', 'Candlestick Maker')}
```

Comment: For performance often the right data structure is the key. Use a dictionary.

Comment: Leaving my deleted answer as a comment for <10k users. *If* your list is assured of having *exactly* matching entries, then you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) along with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) as in `[(x[0],x[1],x[2] , y[1])for x,y in zip(name,occupation)]`

Comment: @BhargavRao I think that's a fair assumption, why else would the OP not show a non-match in the example?

Comment: @StefanPochmann That was one of the reasons why I had answered it in the first case. However it may lead to complications to other visitors. That was the reason why I deleted my answer. In any case the answer is visible to all the users above 10k. So I don't think it is much of a problem. Anyway, if the OP confirms then I will *undelete* it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use dictionaries instead of flat lists.

```
names = {
    9:  ("John", "Smith"),
    11: ("Bob", "Dobbs"),
    14: ("Joe", "Bloggs")
} 

jobs = {
    9:  "Builder",
    11: "Baker",
    14: "Candlestick Maker"
}
```

If you need to convert them to this format, you can do:

```
>>> {id: (first, last) for id, first, last in name}
{9: ('John', 'Smith'), 11: ('Bob', 'Dobbs'), 14: ('Joe', 'Bloggs')}
>>> {id: job for id, job in occupation}
{9: 'Builder', 11: 'Baker', 14: 'Candlestick Maker'}
```

It'd then be a piece of cake to merge the two.

```
names_and_jobs = {id: names[id] + (jobs[id],) for id in names}
```

Comment: This assumes that the 9, 11, and 14 values are unique. What if that's just "years of experience" and not unique at all?

Comment: @TravisGriggs The OP's code treats them like IDs. I am assuming that is the intention.

Comment: @TravisGriggs yes but he is merging only by checking equality for that number, so you can assume they are unique

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import chain

od = OrderedDict()


for ele in chain(name,occupation):
    od.setdefault(ele[0], []).extend(ele[1:])


print([[k]+val for k,val in od.items()])

[[9, 'John', 'Smith', 'Builder'], [11, 'Bob', 'Dobbs', 'Baker'], [14, 'Joe', 'Bloggs', 'Candlestick Maker']]
```

If you want the data ordered by how it appears in names then you need to use an OrderedDict as normal dicts are unordered.

You can also  add the data in the loop creating the desired tuples then just calling od.values to get the list of tuples:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import chain

od = OrderedDict()

for ele in chain(name, occupation):
    k = ele[0]
    if k in od:
        od[k] = od[k] + ele[1:]
    else:
       od[k] = ele

print(od.values())
[(9, 'John', 'Smith', 'Builder'), (11, 'Bob', 'Dobbs', 'Baker'), (14, 'Joe', 'Bloggs', 'Candlestick Maker')]
```

Comment: err *OderederDict*? Too much whisky?

Comment: @BhargavRao the OP's code is iterating over names in order, using a normal dict will mean the data has no order, however the names appear in names this will match the order

Comment: @BhargavRao, it is late ;)